# Set age group based on DOB

Tags: function, google-sheets, group-by

I would like to create a Google Sheet function that if supplied with a date of birth, looks up the below table and gives the appropriate age group. I will be using this table to group 200 kids for surf lifesaving.

for example...date of Birth is 11 Oct 2011, then the age group will be U7. I have use the query function to get this data but I would like to contain it in a function and store the table as a array and compare the date to the array table.

```
- U 5   01 Oct 2013  30 Sep 2017
- U 6    01 Oct 2012     30 Sep 2013
- U 7    01 Oct 2011     30 Sep 2012
- U 8    01 Oct 2010     30 Sep 2011
- U 9    01 Oct 2009     30 Sep 2010
- U 10   01 Oct 2008     30 Sep 2009
- U 11   01 Oct 2007     30 Sep 2008
- U 12   01 Oct 2006     30 Sep 2007
- U 13   01 Oct 2005     30 Sep 2006
- U 14   01 Oct 2004     30 Sep 2005
```

[image: Table to lookup Age Group]

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet with editing rights? That would make it a lot easier to provide you with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be a little tricky. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) to get a better idea. But this script can at least get you started.

This [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q0VjWSEQYhK9IMNjyDqR1yaE_1AvLh_Ks9uZpWEuC-Q/edit?usp=sharing) demonstrates a custom formula (`AGEGROUP`) to compare the input date to a "age-groups" sheet.

**Note:** Only add to "age-groups" sheet if needed. 
The last row with a value is used to consider if someone is too old. 
The first row of the sheet is used to see if someone is too young.

`AGEGROUP()` will accept a cell reference to look up

**Example** `AGEGROUP(B2)`would check cell B2, assuming it contains a date, and return a group assignment (U 5, U 6, U7...).

Looking up dates manually (instead of referencing another cell) can be accomplished by nesting `DATE` inside of `AGEGROUP`. You must follow the right arguments for `DATE` (year, month, day).

**Example** `AGEGROUP(DATE(2010,1,21))`

I'm new to custom functions and did not look into the options for supporting function details like `@param` or `@return` and so on.

**Apps Script**

```
/**
* Finds age group of the input value (date).
*
* @param {date} Input the date to compare to date ranges.
* @return Returns age groupd based on provided date.
* @customfunction
*/

function AGEGROUP(date) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var ages = ss.getSheetByName("age-groups");
  var range = ages.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var i = 0;
  var ranges = values.length;
  var lastRow = ranges -1;

  // loop through dateRanges
  for(i; i < ranges; i++) {   

    // if date in AGEGROUP()
    if(date >= values[i][1] && date <= values[i][2]) {
      // return age group
      return values[i][0];
    }

    // if child is too old
    if(date > values[0][2]) {
      return "Child is too young.";
    }

    // if child is too young
    if(date < values[lastRow][1]) {
      return "Child is too old.";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Guys...Thanks for the quick responses.....Here is a copy of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s6HO3AD3JCRFlGR_ndOmd5msnE_qaQXBo-zt9sVv-3Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: At a glance, your query looks like it should work.  I tried several variations of a query and can't get it to work for I don't know why... An alternative is =FILTER($F$2:$F$11,$G$2:$G$11 <= B2,$H$2:$H$11 >= B2) or if you want to show if they're too old or young  =IF(B2 > $H$2,"too young",IF(B2 < $G$11,"too old",FILTER($F$2:$F$11,$G$2:$G$11 <= B2,$H$2:$H$11 >= B2))). Otherwise the custom function I made in App Script works.